# C - Cannot print structure outside of while loop

Tags: c, list, memory-management, struct, io

The program I am making uses io redirection to read a file line by line, each line being a record in a list. I need to print a structure list but am unable to unless it is from within a while loop . It has previously worked by using a for loop with (i=0,i(lessthan)list.nused;i++) but when I do that nothing prints and there are no errors. Any help would be great, thanks. Here is part of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NAMESIZE 20
#define BLOCK    2
#define BUFSIZE  512

typedef struct {
    char last[NAMESIZE];
    char first[NAMESIZE];
} name;
typedef struct {
    name name;
    int score;
} record;
typedef struct {
    record **data;
    size_t nalloc;
    size_t nused;
} record_list; 
void list_init(record_list *list) {
    list->data = NULL;
    list->nalloc = list->nused = 0;
}
int make_list (record_list *list) {
    int score;
    size_t i;
    char line[BUFSIZE];
    char fname[NAMESIZE];
    char lname[NAMESIZE];
    while (fgets(line, BUFSIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
        if (list->nalloc == list->nused) {
            record *rec = realloc(list->data, (list->nalloc+BLOCK)*sizeof(record));
            if (rec == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unable to resize.");
                clearerr(stderr);
                return 1;
            }
            list->data = &rec;
            list->nalloc += BLOCK;
        }
        if (fgets(line, BUFSIZE, stdin) == NULL) {
            clearerr(stdin);
            return 1;
        }
        sscanf(line, "%s %s %d", fname, lname, &score);
        strcpy(list->data[list->nused]->name.first, fname);
        strcpy(list->data[list->nused]->name.last, lname);
        list->data[list->nused]->score = score;
        list->nused = list->nused++;
        //here is where it is able to print
        //printf("%s\n", list->data[list->nused]->name.last);
    }
    //I would like it to print everything here
    for (i = 0; i < list->nused; i++) {
        printf("%s, %s: %d\n", list->data[i]->name.last,
        list->data[i]->name.first, list->data[i]->score);
    }
    return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    record_list list;
    list_init(&list);
    make_list(&list);
}
```

Comment: Are you claiming your code actually compiles? `list.nused` is invalid as `list` is a pointer. So it has to be `list->nused`. Similarly for some of ther other `list` field accesses. So clearly you have not compiled your code or this is not the right version of the code.

Comment: @kaylum sorry, should compile now

Comment: "Should" compile?? Have you actually tried it? It's still wrong and won't compile. Seems like you aren't even bothering to compile and run your code. So how can we trust the supposed behaviour that you have described?

Comment: 1) `typedef struct {
    record **data;` --> `typedef struct {
    record *data;` then Rewrite the entire code.

Comment: 0) `list->data = &rec;` : Do not use the address of a local variable.

Comment: note `if (fgets(line, BUFSIZE, stdin) == NULL) {` It has already read what was discarded without being used.

Comment: I really don't understand why you keep editing the code but not actually compiling it to verify whether the code you have shown actually compiles. It still won't compile despite your third edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a few small mistakes.  First, change the definition of `record_list` to:

```
typedef struct {
    record *data;
    size_t nalloc;
    size_t nused;
} record_list;
```

You are resizing a block of memory that will hold a number of `record` objects so you should have a pointer to a record instead of a pointer to a pointer -- use the latter if you want to manage a resizable array of pointers.  This requires a few more changes:

- the assignment after the `realloc` call becomes `list->data = rec`
- your assignment of the record data uses member access (`.`) instead of member of a pointer access (`->`) -- in other words, `list->data[list->nused].name.first` instead of `list->data[list->nused]->name.first`

Another subtle mistake is that `list->nused = list->nused++` is just wrong.  It should be `list->nused++` or `list->nused += 1`.

The final mistake is that you are reading each line twice.  You can remove the second call to `fgets`.

You should also be deallocating the memory that you are allocating.  Add `free(list.data)` to the end of main.